# Fuzzy Entity Recognition

Tags: c#, nlp

I am new to NLP.  What I am trying to do (in c#) is given a list of custom entities, along lines of

```
> NAME|ENTITY TYPE|ID
> Cubbies|Baseball Team|CHI
> Chicago Cubs|Baseball Team|CHI
> Dubs|Basketball Team|GSW
> Golden State Warriors|Basketball Team|GSW
```

I am looking to take short sentences and tag fuzzy matches of these entities.

For example, parse

> Jordan Bell is going to make Golden St. much better next year

into

> Jordan Bell is going to make [Basketball Team|GSW] much better next year".

Ideally this would be in conjunction with generalized name recognition eg:

> [Person:Jordan Bell] is going to make [Basketball Team:GSW] much better [Time:next year]".

Grateful for any help or direction.  Thanks!

Comment: Why do you call this fuzzy entity recognition? It looks like regular named-entity recognition to me. You always have to deal with variation in NLP – here, it's abbreviations, synonyms, hyperonyms...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably best to think of your problem in two parts: role labelling (**Named Entity Recognition**) and label unification (fuzzy matching).

For determining labels - that is, marking tokens in the sentences as `team name`, `person`, and so on - a **Conditional Random Field** (CRF) is a good model. [CRF++](https://taku910.github.io/crfpp/) is a popular toolkit. The New York Times used CRF++ with some success on recipe data a few years back. Here's a bit from [their article](https://open.blogs.nytimes.com/2015/04/09/extracting-structured-data-from-recipes-using-conditional-random-fields/):

[image: CRF labelling example]

Since you're identifying the names of sports teams, you have two options for dealing with the fuzzy matching you described. You can do actual fuzzy matching using string similarity; [this article](http://chairnerd.seatgeek.com/fuzzywuzzy-fuzzy-string-matching-in-python/) explains how that was done in Python library Fuzzy Wuzzy at a high enough level it should be easy to re-implement.

Your other option is **Named Entity Resolution**, which is tying named entities (your labelled bits) to an external database. When you do this with Wikipedia it's called "Wikification", for example. [This article](http://www.snee.com/bobdc.blog/2012/12/normalizing-company-names-with.html) describes someone using Wikipedia redirect information to recognize alternate names for companies - you could to the same thing by checking that Wikipedia redirects `Cubbies` to `Chicago Cubs` (it does).

Without knowing your data, it's hard to say whether fuzzy matching or Named Entity Resolution would be easier, so it's probably best to give them both a shot.

Sorry for not including resources explicitly for C# - that said, the techniques here are usually more important than the implementations.